# On international SO sites, migrated questions get the [discussion] tag even though this is a synonym of another one?

Tags: bug, tags, migration, tag-synonyms, localization

I noticed in both Stack Overflow en español and Stack Overflow em Português a bug that may be related to the fact that some default tags are made synonyms to others.

Once a question is posted in the main site and gets migrated into Meta, it gets the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) tag. This is OK by definition.
However, in those sites that tag is a synonym to either [`discusión`](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/discusi%C3%B3n) (in SOes) or [`debate`](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debate) (in SOpt). For this, the question should get the principal, translated tag instead of `discussion`.

Examples:

- [this question](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/3501/revisions) in SOes
- [this question](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6098/empregos-e-imprimir-perfil-pdf) in SOpt

<sub>Note: [I reported this in Meta SOes a while ago](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1391/83), but now I am reporting it here since I saw it happening in Meta SOpt as well.</sub>